# Laravel save simple model as relationship

Tags: laravel

in my web application i have 2 model as `month` and `lessons` that `month` is hasMany with  `lessons`.

that means each lesson record belong to `month` table and each `month` hasMany `lesson`, now this is my models

```
class Month extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'months';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lessons::class);
    }
}


class Lessons extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'section_lessons';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function month()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Month::class);
    }
}
```

now i'm trying to save simple record as relationship with this codes:

```
$month = new \App\Entities\Month;
$month->section_month_name = '';
$month->month_title = '';
$month->section_price = '';
$month->section_available = true;
$month->lessons_count = '';
$month->image = '';
//$month = $month->save();

$lesson = new \App\Entities\Lessons;
$lesson->title = '';
$lesson->content = '';
$lesson->file_url = '';
$lesson->filename = '';
$lesson->time = '';
$lesson->media = '';
$lesson->course = true;
//$lesson->save();

$month->lessons()->save($lesson);
$month->save();
```

i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'month_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `section_lessons` (`title`, `content`, `file_url`, `filename`, `time`, `media`, `course`, `month_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

Migration classes:

```
class Months extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('months', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('section_month_name');
            $table->string('month_title');
            $table->string('section_price');
            $table->boolean('section_available');
            $table->integer('lessons_count');
            $table->text('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('months');
    }
}

class Lessons extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('section_lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('months_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('months_id')->references('id')->on('months')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('content');
            $table->string('file_url');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->string('time');
            $table->string('media');
            $table->boolean('course', false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('section_lessons');
    }
}
```

Comment: put a ```dd($month)``` and show us what you got, please.

Comment: @LucasPiazzi my post updated

Comment: Please read this docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships carefully before posting  questions

Comment: Firslt save `$month`, then relations

Comment: Can you try changing  `months_id` to `month_id` in `section_lessons` table?

Answer (score 1):

The [save()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save) method of an Eloquent object returns a boolean, indicating if the save operation was successful or not.
The object is updated automatically, so change

```
$month = $month->save();
```

to

```
if (!$month->save())
 //Handle error
```

Same with your `$lesson` object.

For your column undefined problem, you have to define `protected $primaryKey = 'id';` in your models, as you are not using the default naming convention (class name in lowercase + dash + id).

You will need to specify the names of those primary keys in your relations, again because of naming conventions, see 
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsTo

Comment: @DolDurma see my updated answer, and have a look at the official Laravel API

Answer (score 1):

If we look into the [API of laravel](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save) we can see the `save()` method on an instance of `...Eloquent\Model` returns a `bool` and not the saved model. Since you have already appointed the new properties to you instance there is (usually) no need to store it again in a variable.

Your final code would look something like:

```
...
$month->save(); // instead of $month = $month->save();
...
```